# Excel keep date format from array using Perl

Tags: perl, spreadsheet

I need to keep the date time format in Excel but it is saving as a plain text in excel.
Please find the code as follows,

```
    use strict;  
    use warnings;
    use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

    my @array = ("Name","2014-04-01 00:00:00AM","2014-04-01 22:00:00AM","Value");
    my $filename = "report.xls";
    my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($filename);
    my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

    $worksheet->write_row($row++,$col,\@array);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hi, it is saving a value as a text format in the column. But it should be a date time format.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states:

```
$worksheet->write_row(0, 0, $array_ref);

# The above example is equivalent to:
$worksheet->write(0, 0, $array[0]);
$worksheet->write(0, 1, $array[1]);
$worksheet->write(0, 2, $array[2]);
```

If you pass an array ref for batch writing, I guess it's not possible to specify what format to use for each column. However, there are other methods like

`write_date_time($row, $col, $date_string, $format)`

You would have to write each row cell separately, but you would get the desired format. (I guess)